# derivative of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

I am a little confused by the proof in the picture.

Doesn't the calculation show $dB(u)h = B(h_1,u_2）+ B(u_1, h_2)$?

[image]

Comment: You are right. The derivative is $dB(u)h= B(u_1,h_2)+B(h_1,u_2)$.

Comment: Right. Typo in $(11)$. Tell the authors and they will be glad.

Comment: thank you guys. This is from Zeidler's applied functional analysis. I imagine there is an errata somewhere...